# Jquery autocomplete, set id 0 on new text

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This code below fills my textbox's autocomplete.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "MyService.asmx/GetCompanies",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#txtCompany').autocomplete({
                        minLength: 0,
                        source: data.d,
                        focus: function (event, ui) {
                            $('#txtCompany').val(ui.item.value);
                            return false;
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            $('#txtCompany').val(ui.item.value);

                            $('#HFCompId').val(ui.item.Name);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
```

When a user selects a name, the id of the name is copied to `HFCompID`, and does good job at it.
But i also need to add new name through the same textbox which is not in the autocomplete. In that case of new name by user, i need to set the value of `HFCompID` to 0.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured it out myself :)
Hope its the correct way. for now its working.
added this after the `select` event

```
change: function (event, ui) {
                            if (ui.item == null) {
                                $('#HFCompId').val(0);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: hmm found out that! the change event get called (with null `ui.item`) even with the item selected. :/